# Правильное условие отправки данных

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
app.post('/order', function (req, res) {
  if (req.body.key.length !=0) {
    let key = Object.keys(req.body.key);
    con.query('SELECT id,name,cost FROM goods WHERE id IN (' + key.join(',') + ')',
        function (error, result, fields) {
            if (error) throw error;
            sendMail(req.body, result).catch(console.error);
            res.send('1');
        });
  } else {
    res.rend('0');
  }
});
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как иначе сделать условие, чтобы если даже нету товара в форме, то происходила отправка. В данный момент, форма в которой присутствует товара, обрабатывается и уходит на почту, а вот там где нету товара, выдает ошибку. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: отправка же происходит `res.rend('0');`

Comment: или вы про отправку почты? тогда поместите вызов и во второе условие, где `res.send(0)`

Comment: да, про почту идет речь

Answer (score 0):

```
app.post('/order', (req, res) => {
  // В самом простом случае.
  if (req.body.key && req.body.key.length !=0) {
    const keys = Object.keys(req.body.key);
    con.query('SELECT id,name,cost FROM goods WHERE id IN (' + keys.join(',') + ')',
        (error, result, fields) => {
            if (error) {
              // Придет текст ошибки
              sendMail(req.body, error).catch(console.error);
              throw error;
            }
            sendMail(req.body, result).catch(console.error);
            res.send('1');
        });
  } else {
    // Отправляем в любом случае
    sendMail(req.body, null).catch(console.error);
    res.rend('0');
  }
});
```

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null

Comment: @Ivan у вас `key` похоже `null`. Это значит, что фронт не передает эти значения, проверяйте наличие этого поля

Comment: да, поэтому старался описать это в постановке задачи, в 1 форму попадают товары, при вызове формы, а вот во вторую форму товары не попадают, и хотелось сделать обработку для двух форм, когда есть товар и когда нету товара

Comment: @Ivan я не понимаю что за форма, почему их две. Почему нужно обрабатывать пустую форму

Comment: не пустую, 1 форма просто для данных: телефон и имя, а вторая форма из карточки товара, где телефон, имя и товар попадает

Comment: @Ivan почему у вас это обрабатывает один роут? Почему не сделать два?

Comment: вот хотелось все в 1 запихнуть, но видно придется на 2 делить, понял вас, спасибо